# Angular 2 Full-calendar is not a function error

Tags: javascript, jquery, angular, npm, fullcalendar

I have installed full-calendar via npm and imported it to my project.It is initialized okay. But when I want to change 'events' like below it gives is not a function error. I just know that it gives this error when Jquery has been imported more than once. But as I see I have imported once and it is before angular js files. So what is the problem?

```
$('angular2-fullcalendar').fullCalendar('refetchEventSources',eventsUrl)
```

Comment: is "angular2-fullcalendar" an element (as in `<angular2-fullcalendar>...</angular2-fullcalendar>`) or should there be a # or . in front of it to indicate an ID or class?

Comment: No, when you include angular2-fullcalendar via npm, you import it as a component. It s a tag.

Comment: ok fair enough. I know fullCalendar quite well but not npm or node. Maybe show the code/markup where you've included the fullCalendar files, and the markup including that angular. Also what is the _exact_ error message given? What is it saying isn't a function?